# SQL - any value in multiple fields

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql, select-by-attribute

I'm looking for a faster SQL that looks for any matches of multiple values in multiple fields. My current method is as so:

`"ORDERNUMBER1" IN ('7006007', '30132084', '7005769') OR "ORDERNUMBER2" IN ('7006007', '30132084', '7005769') OR "ORDERNUMBER3" IN ('7006007', '30132084', '7005769')`

This works, but I wonder if there's a faster way.

I've tried the SQL below but it doesn't work:

`ANY ('7006007', '30132084', '7005769') IN ("ORDERNUMBER1", "ORDERNUMBER2", "ORDERNUMBER3")`

as well as:

`ANY ("ORDERNUMBER1", "ORDERNUMBER2", "ORDERNUMBER3") IN ('7006007', '30132084', '7005769')`

This too fails.

Is there a way to select any of multiple values in multiple fields?

Comment: Are the 3 'ORDERNUMBER' fields indexed?

Comment: @Radar Yes they are.

Comment: Thiis is one of the reasons to *avoid* creating ORDERNUMBER1/... fields and instead properly model the tables in third order normal form with a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: Are you trying to Select these records in ArcMap?  What about some arcpy search cursors and a `setSelectionSet()`?

Comment: @Vince I agree, but I have to work with the data provided.

Answer (score 1):

In standard SQL (and Postgres) this is a valid equivalent:

```
EXISTS ( VALUES ("ORDERNUMBER1"), ("ORDERNUMBER2"), ("ORDERNUMBER3") 
         INTERSECT 
         VALUES ('7006007'), ('30132084'), ('7005769')
       )
```

But note that because the syntax is more compact, it doesn't mean that the query will magically be more efficient. With 3 indexes, on each of the 3 columns, I'd expect your first query to result in a better plan. But you can surely test in your installation.

You can also use the first query, with multiple `OR` and compact the syntax - not repeat the parameter values -  using a CTE:

```
WITH v (i) AS
  ( VALUES ('7006007'), ('30132084'), ('7005769') )
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE 
      ( "ORDERNUMBER1" IN (TABLE v)
     OR "ORDERNUMBER2" IN (TABLE v)
     OR "ORDERNUMBER3" IN (TABLE v)
      ) ;
```